# Does querying by key in Firestore have performance issues?

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to retrieve a result set of all documents in a collection that contain a particular key. The structure of the collection is:

```
conversations {

    conversationId1 {
        uid1: true
        uid2: true
    }

    conversationId2 {
        uid3: true
        uid4: true
    }

}
```

so my query for all conversations with uid1 as a participant would look like:

`conversations.whereField('uid1', isEqualTo: true)`

While this returns a correct dataset (only conversations with field uid1 existing) I assume that, since the collection is not indexed by field *names*, there would be a performance issue once the collection size grows. Is that the case?